# REST API not responding to jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, node.js, rest

I'm building a REST API (w/ ExpressJS on Node) as part of my current project, but am running into a strange issue when I try and do a POST via jQuery.

When I trigger this call from my UI, and watch the Network tab of Chrome's devtools - the call hangs for awhile before failing. Obviously something is happening on the server end. Jumping to my node console, it looks like whenever I make this POST, my console outputs something like this:

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "jquery-1.10.2.min.map" at path "_id"',
name: 'CastError',
type: 'ObjectId',
value: 'jquery-1.10.2.min.map',
path: '_id' }
```

This is a Mongoose error message if I'm not mistaken. However, breakpoints in my API Code are never hit. It looks like something is happening between the jQuery call and the API execution. I'll attach the source code below in case that proves useful. Has anyone seen something like this before?

#### jQuery

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/DataPoint/UpdateIdentifier",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            dataPointID : dataPointID,
            newValue : newVal,
            identifierIndex: identifierIndex
        },
        complete: dataUpdateCompleteHandler,
        success: dataUpdateSuccessHandler,
        error: dataUpdateErrorHandler
    });
```

#### API Code

```
app.post("/api/DataPoint/UpdateIdentifier", function(req, res){

var datapointID = req.body.dataPointID,
    newValue = req.body.newValue,
    identifierIndex = req.body.identifierIndex;

DataPoint.findById(datapointID)
.exec(function(err, datapoint){

    if (err) return console.log(err);

    datapoint.customIdentifiers[identifierIndex] = newValue;
    datapoint.save(function(err){
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else res.send(200); 
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable maps by editing your copy of jquery.

As far as the non-response goes, I'd guess it's that you're logging the error to stdout, but you're not responding to the request. So change this:

```
if (err) return console.log(err);
```

to something like:

```
if (err) {
  err.status = 500;
  next(err);
  // or use `res.json(err);` instead of `next(err);` if that's what
  // you're expecting on the client side
  return console.log(err);
}
```

and add `next` after `res` in that route handler's function parameter list:

```
app.post("/api/DataPoint/UpdateIdentifier", function(req, res, next){
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really help. Whatever error is being thrown by jQuery, its coming from somewhere other than my copy. I'm using the latest version (2.1.1), and adding the map file didn't change anything. Also, handling the `err` differently doesn't help, as I've found from debugging that no code in the API route is executed. Its like something is happening in express' router?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code (especially the middleware you are using and in what order).